# In Ews push notification mode, I am getting unwanted unsaved Appointment. How to get rid of them?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Web Services' push notification mode. I noticed that when I "New an appointment" in Exchange, if I click "attachment" button, it jumps to Attachement page, and push a "Item" notification into the SOAP servlet right away, without me "Save" the appointment. I guess this is probably how it works. But then I need to identify this "Item" as unfinished in my code, such that I can ignore it until I received another notification when the appointment is actually saved. So far, I've tried a number of properties such as `isDraft`, `isDirty`, `getAppointmentState` and etc to identify this "unsaved" appointment, but none of them worked.

So my questions are:

1. Can I config the exchange server such that it stops pushing notification for "unsaved" appointment?
2. Failing to do (1), how can I identify the "unsaved" appointment? Which property to check?

Thanks in advance,

Ling

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are basically just telling you that an Item has been created on the server and based on way the UI action is taking place the client is creating an item to cater for the UI interaction so you will get a notification regardless. There is no such concept as a draft appointment and then next notification you get for that appointment should be an update. Multiple notification for an appointment is something that your code you should expect and deal with if you synchronization process is going to work reliably.

One thing you can try is to look at the item that is being created with a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy or MFCMapi as that will tell you if there is a specific extended property that you maybe able to use.